# Convert transformer resistance data from Watts to Ohm

Tags: ohms-law, conversion, power-engineering

Short version: How can I convert transformer resistance values from Watts to Ohms?

Long version: In PSS/E, transformer resistance can be entered as either per unit values (system base or transformer base), or as a MW-value (I believe this represents loss at full load).

[image]

How can I convert the values from I/O code 3 to I/O code 1? That is from pu based on winding kV and system MVA-rating to full load loss and per unit impedance (for reactance).

```
Voltage level: 125/11 kV
System MVA rating: 100 MVA
Transformer rating: 35 MVA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at some transformer test results for a 60 MVA 132/33kV transformer, and found this in the test results:

[image]

This seems to suggest that the resistance, in percent on transformer MVA base (60 MVA), is simply Load Loss [W] ÷ Transformer MVA Base [MVA]. In this case, that's 381,000 W ÷ 60,000,000 MVA = 0.635%. Enter this for 'I/O Code 2'.

Similarly, the percent impedance on system MVA base (typically 100 MVA) would just be 381,000W ÷ 100 MVA = 0.381%. Enter this for 'I/O Code 1'.

Comment: Yes, you are right :) I figured it out a few days ago too. I thought I'd answer the question myself once the bounty expired, but you got to it first. Thanks for validating the answer with the test report!

Comment: I stumbled upon this again today. I guess the answer is correct, but I find it strange. I would think that the resistance should correspond to the R in "I2R Loss", not Load Loss %. The load loss includes the no-load losses, which is not dependent on R. The no load losses is a separate input parameter. I know that when entering Load Loss (W), then the no load loss is automatically included, but why it should be included when entering the resistance is beyond me.